# call a function after create, write or unlink

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

```html
    def clean_data(self):
      do some stuffs
```

how can I call it every time after write, create or unlink?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override the create, write and unlink methods and call your function:

```py
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    res = super(YourModel, self).create(vals)
    self.clean_data()        
    return res

@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    res = super(YourModel, self).write(vals)
    self.clean_data()  
    return res

@api.multi
def unlink(self):
    res = super(YourModel, self).unlink()
    self.clean_data() 
    return res
```

I hope this help you!